# is there any difference in terms of scope, lifetime?

Tags: java, reference, scope, lifetime

First program:

```
class Demo  {
   public static void main(String args[])  {
      Object obj ;
      while(true)  {
         obj = new Object();
      }
   }
}
```

2nd program:

```
class Demo  {
   public static void main(String args[])  {
      Object obj = null;
      while(true)  {
         obj = new Object();
      }
   }
}
```

question : is there any difference in terms of scope of `obj` in the two programs where obj is assigned value in the loop(in first program) and obj is assigned null value initially (in second program).

Comment: Does your first program run with no error?

Comment: yes it runs with no error...

Comment: Ok, actually the default value of Object type is `null`. so intializint it to `null` or not initializing it is the same.

Comment: you are wrong .. actually the concept of initialization of vars with their default value is done for the instance variables ,not for local vars as in this case , by the constructors...

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the scope of `obj` is till the end of the main method. Both programs will run infinitely because of the `while(true)` condition.

In the first case however, an attempt to use `obj` outside the loop will cause compilation error since its not initialized (Assuming the while loop terminates at some point)

```
public static void main(String []args){
        Object obj;
        while(args != null)  {
             obj = new Object();
        }
       System.out.println(obj); //compilation error
}
```

Comment: wrong.. there will be no compilation error..

Comment: why don't you try it and check for yourself: http://ideone.com/xa2Hng

Comment: @nihal using `obj` outside loop will result in the compilation error because of `unreachable code` in your post. In Nikhils example that's because of `uninitialized local variable`. compiler checks if a local variable is initialized through every possible path before reaching to the statement where its being used.

Comment: ok.. but i was asking about the scope lifetime of uninitialized local variable....

Comment: see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737477/in-the-given-program-the-garbage-collector-is-running-before-the-object-is-deref/24738830#24738830